# Как в Unity3d использовать возможности C# 5/6/7?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-faq

Захотел я идти в ногу со временем, посмотрел новые фишки и плюшки C#6/7, воодушевился. Там так всё вкусно и круто, что грех не пользоваться. Открыл *Unity*, *Visual Studio*, написал пару строк и...впал в уныние. На любые попытки использования новых фич мне говорят одно:

> Feature *bla bla bla* is not available in C#4. Please use language version 6 or greater

или

> Feature *bla bla bla* cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 4.0 language specification

Посмотрел версию *Mono*, которую использует *Unity 5.6* (**!!! самая последняя версия**) и это было: `2.0 (Visual Studio built mono)`. В итоге в ней есть всё, что есть в C#3, плюс часть из C#4.

Это меня не очень радует и устраивает.

Есть ли какая возможность, всё-таки, использовать новые версии языка, а не застыть в далёком 2010-ом? Что можно сделать и как?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**UPDATE (12.01.2021)**

Согласно [данным](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CSharpCompiler.html) теперь можно использовать нативно и C# 7.3

В документации по бета-версии 2020.1 все еще упоминается 7.3, но в 2020.2 указано, что она будет поддерживать 8.0.

---

Старый ответ для других версий юнити

Да, можно использовать новые версии, но с оговорочкой...об этом ниже.

Хоть *Unity* и застряла на долгое время на *CLR 2.0*, тем не менее новые фичи C# не требуют самой последней версии *CLR*. Компиляторы *Microsoft* и  *Mono* могут скомпилировать *C# 5/6/7* для *CLR 2.0* если их явно об этом попросить.

**Замечание:** однако некоторые фичи все же недоступны, например такие как `dynamic`.

---

Итак, эту возможность (и, на данный момент, может быть единственную) можно найти в репозитории битбакета **[Unity C# 5.0 and 6.0 Integration](https://web.archive.org/web/20190110002819/https://bitbucket.org/alexzzzz/unity-c-5.0-and-6.0-integration/src)**

## Что надо сделать?

- Для C# 6.0

  1. Скопировать папку `CSharp60Support` из репозитория (или со **[страницы закачки](https://web.archive.org/web/20200702182053/https://bitbucket.org/alexzzzz/unity-c-5.0-and-6.0-integration/downloads/)**) к себе в *Unity* проект. Папку необходимо поместить в корень проекта, **рядом с папкой** `Assets`. **НЕ во внутрь!**
  2. Импортировать `CSharp60Support.unitypackage` (находится в папке `CSharp60Support`) в свой проект.
  3. Перезагрузить *Unity*
  4. [По желанию - не обязательно]: На *Windows* - запустить `/CSharp60Support/ngen install.cmd` с *правами администратора*. Команда скомпилирует csc.exe, pdb2mdb.exe и mcs.exe используя **[Ngen](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator)**, что позволит производить компилирование в *Unity* чуточку быстрее.
- Для C# 7.0

  1. Для *MacOS* скачать и установить **[Mono 4.6+](https://www.mono-project.com/download/)**. Для *Windows* скачать и установить **[.Net Framework 4.6.2+](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53345)**.
  2. Скопировать папку `CSharp70Support`  из репозитория (или со **[страницы закачки](https://web.archive.org/web/20200702182053/https://bitbucket.org/alexzzzz/unity-c-5.0-and-6.0-integration/downloads/)**) к себе в *Unity* проект. Папку необходимо поместить в корень проекта, **рядом с папкой** `Assets`. **НЕ во внутрь!**
  3. Импортировать `CSharp70Support.unitypackage`(находится в папке `CSharp70Support`) в свой проект.
  4. Перезагрузить *Unity*
  5. [По желанию - не обязательно] На *Windows* - запустить `/CSharp70Support/ngen install.cmd` с *правами администратора*. Команда скомпилирует csc.exe, pdb2mdb.exe и mcs.exe используя **[Ngen](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator)**, что позволит производить компилирование в *Unity* чуточку быстрее.

Таким образом изменению подвергается только папка с **текущим** проектом. Остальные проекты будут работать как обычно с текущей версией языка, Mono и прочей жестью :)

## Как это работает?

1. `/Assets/CSharp vNext Support/Editor/CSharpVNextSupport.dll` - расширение для редактора, которое через рефлексию изменяет внутренние данные редактора, говоря ему, чтобы тот использовал альтернативный компилятор C# (`/CSharpXXSupport/CSharpCompilerWrapper.exe`). Если он не существует, то используется дефолтный.
2. `CSharpCompilerWrapper.exe` получает и перенаправляет запросы на компиляцию от *Unity* к одному из актуальных C# компиляторов, которые используют следующие правила:

   - Если существует папка `CSharp70Support` и она содержит папку `Roslyn`, то используется компилятор C# 7.0;
   - Если существует папка `CSharp60Support` и она содержит папку `Roslyn`, то используется компилятор C# 6.0;
   - Иначе если существует папка `CSharp60Support` и она содержит `mcs.exe`, то использует компилятор *Mono C# 6.0*;
   - В ином случае используется компилятор по дефолту (`/Unity/Editor/Data/Mono/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe`).

Убедитесь, что компилятор `CSharpCompilerWrapper.exe` действительно работает! Для этого посмотрите в логи компиляции: `UnityProject/CSharpXXSupport/compilation.log`

## Какие платформы поддерживаются?

Работает это на всех основных платформах:

- Windows (editor and standalone)
- MacOS (editor and standalone)
- Android
- iOS

Чуть больше информации и небольших ограничениях вы можете почитать на  **[главной странице репозитория](https://web.archive.org/web/20190110002819/https://bitbucket.org/alexzzzz/unity-c-5.0-and-6.0-integration/src)**, а также (т.к. основная информация дана выше) в виде цитаты с источника на английском языке:

> ## Response (.rsp) files
>
> If you want to use a response file to pass extra options to the compiler (e.g. `-unsafe`), the file must be named `CSharpCompilerWrapper.rsp`.

> ## platforms are "supported"
>
> On MacOS the Roslyn compiler cannot create debug information files (.pdb) that Unity can consume. If you compile your code with Roslyn on MacOS you won't be able to debug it.
>
> Since WebGL doesn't offer any multithreading support, AsyncBridge and
> Task Parallel Library are not available for this platform. Caller Info
> attributes are also not available, because their support comes with
> AsyncBridge library.
>
> AsyncBridge/TPL stuff is also not compatible with Windows Store
> Application platform (and probably all the platforms that use .Net
> runtime instead of Mono runtime) due to API differences between the
> recent versions of .Net Framework and the ancient version of TPL
> (System.Threading.dll) that comes with AsyncBridge. Namely, you can't
> use async/await, Caller Info attributes and everything from
> System.Threading.dll (concurrent collections for example).
>
> ## Other known issues
>
> - C# 5.0/6.0 is not compatible with Unity Cloud Build service for obvious reason.
> - Using Mono C# 6.0 compiler may cause occasional Unity crashes while debugging in Visual Studio -
>   http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/c-6-0.314297/page-2#post-2225696
> - IL2CPP doesn't support exception filters added in C# 6.0 (ExceptionFiltersTest.cs).
> - If a MonoBehaviour is declared inside a namespace, the source file should not contain any C# 6.0-specific language constructions before
>   the MonoBehaviour declaration. Otherwise, the editor won't recognize
>   the script as a MonoBehaviour component.
>
>   Bad example:
>
>   ```
>     using UnityEngine;
>     using static System.Math; // C# 6.0 syntax!
>
>     namespace Foo
>     {
>      class Baz
>      {
>         object Qux1 => null; // C# 6.0 syntax!
>         object Qux2 { get; } = null; // C# 6.0 syntax!
>      }
>
>       class Bar : MonoBehaviour { } // "No MonoBehaviour scripts in the file, or their names do not match the file name."
>     }
>   ```
>
>   Good example:
>
>   ```
>     using UnityEngine;
>
>     namespace Foo
>     {
>      class Bar : MonoBehaviour { } // ok
>
>      class Baz
>      {
>         object Qux1 => null;
>         object Qux2 { get; } = null;
>      }
>     }
>   ```
> - There's a bug in Mono C# 6.0 compiler, related to null-conditional operator support (NullConditionalTest.cs):
>
>   ```
>     var foo = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
>     var bar = foo?[0];
>     Debug.Log((foo?[0]).HasValue); // error CS1061: Type `int' does not 
>     // contain a definition for `HasValue' and no extension method
>     // `HasValue' of type `int' could be found. Are you missing an
>     // assembly reference?
>   ```
>
>   Mono compiler thinks that `foo?[0]` is `int` while it's actually `Nullable<int>`. However, `bar`'s type is deduced correctly -
>   `Nullable<int>`.
>
> ## License
>
> All the source code is published under [WTFPL version
> 2](http://www.wtfpl.net/about/).
>
> ## Want to talk about it?
>
> http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/c-6-0.314297/#post-2108999
>
> ## Random notes
>
> - Roslyn C# 6.0 compiler was taken from VS 2015 installation. C# 7.0 compiler was taken from VS 15 Preview 5 installation.
> - `mcs.exe`, `pdb2mdb.exe` and its dependencies were taken from [Mono 4.4.1.0](https://www.mono-project.com/download/) installation. pdb2mdb.exe that comes with Unity is not compatible with the assemblies generated with Roslyn compiler.
> - AsyncBridge library contains a set of types that makes it possible to use *async/await* in projects that target CLR 2.0. It also provides
>   Caller Info attributes support. For more information, check [this blog
>   post](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/).
> - If you use *async/await* inside Unity events (Awake, Start, Update etc) you may notice that continuations (the code below `await`
>   keyword) are executed in background threads. Most likely, this is not
>   what you would want. To force `await` to return the execution to the
>   main thread, you'll have to provide it with a synchronization context,
>   like all WinForms and WPF applications do.
>
>   Check `UnityScheduler.cs`, `UnitySynchronizationContext.cs` and `UnityTaskScheduler.cs` example implementations located in the
>   project. These classes create and register several synchronization
>   contexts for the Unity's main thread, so async/await could work the
>   way they do in regular WinForms or WPF applications.
>
>   For more information about what synchronization context is, what it is for and how to use it, see this set of articles by Stephen Toub:
>   [one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx), [two](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/21/10259307.aspx), [three](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps-part-3/).

---

**P.S.** Попробую отслеживать тему и держать ссылку на свежую версию актуальной.

Answer (score 1):

На  текущий момент (12.01.2020) в Unity версия языка C# 7.3 [пруф](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CSharpCompiler.html)  и не надо производить специальных действий, всё доступно из коробки, поправьте меня если ошибаюсь.

Comment: Да, вроде так..