# Unity: Debug.Log для множество объектов

Tags: unity3d

Очень часто случается так что надо с помощью Debug.Log() выводить множество объектов но это нельзя сделать циклом т.к. они разные объекты. **Есть какой то способ с помощью одного Debug.Log() выводить множество объектов?**

Comment: На самом деле не очень понятно,мб есть конкретный пример?

Comment: разве что с помощью `string.Format` или если с фичами C# 6.0, через интерполяцию строк `$"{obj1}, {obj2}"`

Comment: @TEA Ну например у меня есть 4 переменные - a,b,c,d. Чтобы их всех выводить я должен 
писать
    Debug.Log(a);
    Debug.Log(b);
    Debug.Log(c);
    Debug.Log(d);
Можно как то сделать что то типо этого - 
    Debug.Log(a, b, c, d);

Comment: @trollingchar у меня C# 4.0. И у меня 2 вопросы - 
1.версия C# можно обновить отдельно от Unity?
2.Как вы писали код в комментариях?

Comment: Код пишется так же, как и в вопросах/ответах - тильда. Да, в юнити можно использовать фишки из шарпов более новых версий - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688209/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-unity3d-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-c-5-6-7

Comment: @AltF4 C# 6.0 можно включить в **Edit - Project Settings - Player** там выбрать в **Other Settings** версию .NET 4.x и перезагрузить юнити. На этом все, но в старых версиях не работает. Про код уже ответили.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void Start()
{
    string a = "A";
    int b = 14;
    bool c = true;
    char d = 'w';

    print(a + b + c + d); 
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS print вроде бы новее и его рекомендуют использовать вместо Debug.Log,debug.log,вроде бы,нужно использовать в коде для вывода ошибок warning & критических

Либо так:

```
  void Start()
    {
        string a = "A";
        int b = 14;
        bool c = true;
        char d = 'w';

        print(string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", a.ToString() , b.ToString() ,c.ToString() ,d.ToString()));
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]